# ElasticSuite Reindex Fatal Error

Tags: magento2, reindex, elasticsearch

I'm trying to reindex Elastic Search but I'm running into an error I don't know how to fix.
The reindexing runs fine on 2 other machines.

I've deleted all indices with the "curl -X DELETE [http://0.0.0.0:9200/_all"](http://0.0.0.0:9200/_all%22) command which returned {"acknowledged":true}, however, the issue still persists.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had to adjust to code to alter a null value into a boolean in this file to make it work:

vendor\magento\module-page-builder\Model\Stage\Preview.php

```
/**
 * Determine if the system is in preview mode
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function isPreviewMode() : bool
{
    if ($this->isPreview)
    {
      return false;
    }
    return $this->isPreview;
}
```